# Having issues mounting an old DOS hard drive from a mid 90s 486 machine on Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, mount, ms-dos

I'm trying to mount an old hard drive from a mid 90's 486 for file recovery. The harddrive (Matrox 7850 AV) is identified correctly by the motherboard (Asus P5QL PRO), but it can't be mounted in Slacko Puppy Linux or Parted Magic.

```
udevil: error 64: unable to determine device fstype
```

`fdisk -l` lists the drive's size correctly and identifies the filesystem as `OnTrack DM6`.

BTW, the 486 machine in question still runs, and the hard drive seems to be working fine.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

OnTrack DM6 is a Disk Manager used to support large disks back in the days when BIOS couldn't handle them. Here is something to try, suggested in [this thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/partition-recovery-ontrack-disk-manager-gone-471710/),

- connect the hdd
- power on PC or reboot depending where you are at...
- at grub menu press `e` to edit line
- move cursor to the **end of the line** that starts with `linux /vmlinuz....`
- add the option hdX=remap63 or sdX=remap63 depending how it appears on your system
- press `Ctrl+X` to boot with modified line

it *should* then be able to correctly read the partition table of your old drive.

If this works, you then need to change your grub configuration to include that option every time. [This page](http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20Configuration%20File%20Commands.html) is a good starting point on how to go about changing your grub config.

Comment: Since I'm not that familiar with editing the grub conf, I have to ask: 1. fdisk lists the drive as sda, so the above line would be sda=remap63, right? Where exactly should I add this option while editing the grub boot line? I'm booting into Debian Wheezy, FWIW.

Comment: Yes change hdX to sda. As for the grub line, I'll edit the answer with more info.

Comment: This is the way I tried it the first time, now gave it another go but as far as i can see, the sda=remap63 option has no effect whatsoever. I did check the thread you linked to and it seemed to be the exact same situation, only it was solved this way. Can it be this option has been removed from later kernels?

Comment: The sda, sdb labels can change with each reboot (in Debian-based distros, I think any distro), sda is sdb next time...

Comment: I did check for that after each reboot, and the label corresponded with the one I gave the remap command for. I'm still completely open for suggestions on this problem but am also preparing to move the files via floppy from the old machine. It's about 180 MB, however, and does seem a bit brutish ;)

Comment: Only other idea I can think of is using a virtual machine. Do you have any recent version of Windows in a VM? You may get lucky that way...

Comment: [Hiren's CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/hbcd-v98/) claims to have Ontrack recovery software. Nothing to lose I guess...

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this thread looking for an answer.  I finally managed to access data from my old drive, so in case if anyone will need to mount an old disk with the Ontrack DiskManager DM6 (`remap` is now removed from the kernel):

1. On your old computer from which you can access the ancient IDE drive, copy the entire disk, say `/dev/sdb`,  with:

   `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=disk.raw`

   For your convenience you can copy the raw image to your normal desktop.
2. mount with skipping the first 63 sectors. Assuming 512 bytes/sector:

   `sudo losetup --partscan --find --show -o 32256  disk.raw`
3. check out `sudo fdisk /dev/loop0 -l`, you should be able to see all your partitions, named /dev/loop0p1 etc.
4. `sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/mountpoint` and you'll get the first partition in the mountpoint.

Of course you can try mounting it without making the image of the disk (by skipping 1).

Comment: This answer was so legit for me, I had an old IDE drive with an 8 gb partition, that had that Disk Manager thingee, and what looked like a free 137GB parition (but it wasn't). So I did not copy the drive to a RAW file, instead I just ran #2 against my /dev/sde (not sde1) because that was the 137GB partition. Voila!
THANKS HEAPS!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to mount the two partitions of a 25 year old hard disk I have using brute force. The disk was so old that `fdisk -l` couldn't list the partitions, it only listed the whole disk as one partition with type `OnTrackDM6`. Didn't find a way to access it, so I ran the following commands as root.

First, I dumped the hard disk to a file so the data was rescued and I didn't have to use the ancient machinery:

```
ddrescue /dev/sdb hda.img hda.map
```

Then I scanned through the whole disk, trying to mount every 512th byte offset:

```sh
mkdir hda1
seq 0 512 1089994752 | while read f; do
  echo $f;
  mount hda.img hda1 -o ro,offset=$f && break;
done
```

The first partition got mounted on `hda1/` in a few seconds. After I copied all the files to another location, I unmounted `hda1/`, increased the first argument of `seq` by the byte count of files in hda1 rounded down to the nearest multiple of 512 (it's important that the first `seq` argument is divisible by 512 or whatever `fdisk -l` reports the sector size as) and ran it again. It found the next partition in 5-10 minutes or so and I was able to copy all the files to another location before unmounting the disk and forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to indicate the file system type with `-t`

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdxx /media/path/to/mount
```

if it doesn't work try `fat`, `msdos` and `umsdos`.

Comment: mount -t (vfat/msdos) generates the error message "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock..."

Comment: It seems that it is not DOS and that's why it's not working. **OnTrack MD6** is a different kind of file system.